# Cannot retrieve parent id on child v-for in Edge

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microsoft-edge

I have a form which contains a parent element and a child element, in every browser I can retrieve this value but in MS Edge I am unable to get the key from the parent element. Is anyone able to shed light on this issue?

```
<div v-for="(levelKey, level) in levels">
     @{{ level.name }}

     <div v-for="(currencyKey, currency) in currencies">
          <input type="text" name="levels[@{{ level.id }}][currency.id]" v-model="...">
     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct: `level[@{{ level.id }}]`. Looks like it should either be `levels[level.id]` or simply `level[level.id]`? Or `currency[level.id]`?

Comment: sorry it shoul read levels[@...] have updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your `type` attribute as a bound attribute using the `:type` syntax. See: https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html

Then you don't need the moustache braces (`@{{ ... }}`) when you're already inside an expression. You can just write:

```
<input :name="levels[level.id][currency.id]" v-model="...">
```

or even simpler (since you're already looping through `levels`):

```
<input :name="level[currency.id]" v-model="...">
```

**EDIT**

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tp6kcdnf/3/) with some mock data (probably not exactly the same as yours, though) and tried it in MS Edge. It worked fine:

[image]

Maybe you forgot to copy a part of the code?

Comment: Outside of the v-model it will just return the text (e.g. currency.id) in the name of the input. (Also for the record, I didn't down vote your answer)

Comment: What do you mean with *outside of the v-model*?

Comment: if I do <input name="levels[level.id][currency.id]"> it will output levels[level.id][currency.id]. I need the braces to return it levels[1][2]

Comment: My bad, of course the type should be a dynamic property using the `:`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't made a difference to MS Edge. Also type should actually be name not type.

Comment: Yes. Everyone apart from Edge

Comment: What do you get in edge in the `name` attribute? And do you get any errors?

Comment: It doesn't calculate level.id - e.g. levels[][3]

Comment: @SimonR I created a test fiddle and tested it in MS Edge. It seems to work, try for yourself.